# Select one appointment before date for each patient (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I just had to do this for one patient:

```
SELECT * FROM appts where pat_id = 1 and date < '2015-05-20' order by date dsc;
```

But I need to get this for every patient:

```
SELECT * FROM appts as a, patients as p where a.pat_id=p.id a.date < '2015-05-20';
```

But this doesn't work, because it doesn't limit the number of appointments to 1 per patient, and it isn't sorted by date per patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by user and select the latest date

```
SELECT pat_id, MAX(date) FROM appts as a WHERE date < '2015-05-20' GROUP BY pat_id;
```

If you have to you can join the patients table.

Comment: MAX(column_name), ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` and use `ORDER BY`, not sort.  Also note that it is generally considered a better practice to use explicit join syntax rather than just saying "`a.pat_id=p.id a.date`".

```
create table patients  (
  pat_id  numeric,
  pat_name varchar(20)
);

create table appts  (
  pat_id  numeric,
  date date
);

insert into patients values (1,'Anne');
insert into patients values (2,'Bob');
insert into patients values (3,'Chris');
insert into patients values (4,'David');

insert into appts values (1,'2015-01-20');
insert into appts values (1,'2015-05-21');
insert into appts values (2,'2015-03-20');
insert into appts values (2,'2015-04-20');
insert into appts values (3,'2015-05-21');
```

Query:

```
select p.pat_id, p.pat_name, max(a.date) as appt_date
from patients p
join appts a
on p.pat_id = a.pat_id
where a.date < '2015-05-20'
group by p.pat_id, p.pat_name
order by appt_date desc;
```

Result:

```
pat_id  pat_name    appt_date
2       Bob         April, 20 2015 00:00:00
1       Anne        January, 20 2015 00:00:00
```

Comment: @b7kich, that question is not relevant.  It relates to using non-aggregated columns in the SELECT list, which my answer does NOT do.

Comment: Ah - you're right - sorry